# How to avoid using asInstanceOf in Scala

Tags: scala, casting, factory, classcastexception

Currently my code needs class casting

```
val dataWriter: BytesDataWriter = createDataWriter

 def createDataWriter(p: SomeClass) =
    p.create_datawriter().asInstanceOf[BytesDataWriter]
```

The `create_datawriter` method will return the superclass DataWriter. Instead of casting it using `asInstanceOf`, I tried this approach

```
val dataWriter: BytesDataWriter = createDataWriter(p)  match {
      case writer: BytesDataWriter => writer
      case _ => throw new ClassCastException
    }
```

This is too verbose, and in case case does not work. Is there a better alternative to class casting?

Comment: `asInstanceOf` is "fine" here and does the sane thing of throwing an exception if the runtime cast fails (just as the manual case) - if you want better, fix the returned type.

Comment: What is the return type of p.create_datawriter()?

Comment: @RadoBuransky `create_datawriter()` returns the type `DataWriter` hence the need to cast.

Comment: @user2864740 This should be an answer.

Comment: The general answer to "How to avoid type casts?" is "Keep the type information when you still have it, e.g. don't throw it away if you will need it again."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would use the second approach in case you can do *something* with a non-`BytesDataWriter` result, or to get a better error message:

```
val dataWriter: BytesDataWriter = p.create_datawriter() match {
  case writer: BytesDataWriter => writer
  case other => throw new Exception(s"Expected p to create a BytesDataWriter, but got a ${other.getClass.getSimpleName} instead!")
}
```

Otherwise, use `asInstanceOf`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Alexey Romanov is a good advice for your specific situation. Alternatively you could try to avoid this situation by changing the sctructure of the surrounding code.

### Can your problem be reformulated?

When you are using a class and instantiate it, it looks like you are implementing some kind of configurable dependency handling. This is a complex problem, but fortunately there are some good solutions for this:

### Dependency injection

You could use some kind of dependency injection and inject the needed `ByteDataWriter` with the specialized type. Look at the "Robot Leg" example described in the [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) on how to deal with different variants of the same base class, and on [how to deal with generics](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html). This might help you to avoid your problem with `DataWriter` and `ByteDataWriter`.

### Duck typing

You can also access your `DataWriter` with a protocol (or in Scala speak: [a strucutral type](http://java.dzone.com/articles/duck-typing-scala-structural)). Structural typs will not be checked at compile time, so no need for a class cast.

### Cake pattern

Or you can handle you dependencies using a Scala specialty: The [cake pattern](https://github.com/eigengo/opensourcejournal/blob/master/cake-pattern/cake.md). With this pattern you can compose your class just as needed. You can design the class needing the `ByteDataWriter` completely type safe. The compiler will then make sure, that it can only combined with the correct class. No need for a class cast. The disadvantage is, that you cannot reconfigure the dependencies using a config file. But usually this is not necessary, because the supported variants are well known at compile time.

### Conclusion: Try to reformulate when possible

If you have the option, consider to re-design your code using one of the methods described above, to get rid of the class cast. It is very likely that you will have the same problem on many other places in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much @stefan.schwetschke, did you just read my mind? :) I wanted to explore functional and less declarative approach that produce clean and concise code. Not really sure how to formulate the question without sounding too vague.

Comment: With some experience it is easy to guess what the root cause might be, when you see certain patterns. Read the material behind the supplied links. And just ask when you have some problems. Good luck!