# Scala casting and avoiding asInstanceOf

Tags: scala

In the following code, is it possible to reformulate without using asInstanceOf? I found some styleguide suggestions that asInstanceOf/isInstanceOf should be avoided, and I managed to clean up my code except for the usage shown below.

I did find a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129943/how-to-avoid-using-asinstanceof-in-scala), but it didn't really help me for this particular case, or I'm just too much of a beginner to translate it to my own use case.

```
trait pet {}
class dog extends pet {
  def bark: String = {
    "WOOF"
  }
}

def test(what: pet) : String =
{
  what match {
    case _:dog =>
      val x = what.asInstanceOf[dog]
      x.bark
  }
}

test(new dog())
```

I tried for example:

```
val x = what : dog
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just specify in case section that you expect `dog` object:

```
case x: dog => x.bark
```

But now you might receive `scala.MatchError` if non-dog object will be passed to your method. So you need to add default case with desirable behavior like this:

```
case _ => "unknown pet"
```